# DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client on Mojave and Xcode 10.1

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, macos-mojave, xcode10.2

This error constantly appearing in the `system.log`:

> DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug

The code in question is given bellow:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self doItInTheBackground];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.loadingSpinner stopAnimation:self];
        [self.loadingPanel close];
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Any program using GCD library seems to be getting this error, including systems apps like Terminal, Console, AppStore, etc.

**EDIT 2:**

As of 10.14.4, I can see several other messages as well, e.g.:

> DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug

And

> BUG in libdispatch client: mach_recv, monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked { 0xXXXXXXXXXXXX[source], ident: XX / 0xXX, handler: 0xXXXXXXXXXXXX }

Comment: How did you determine that that was the code causing the log message? And what does `-doItInTheBackground` actually do?

Comment: Prints `Initialized` that's all. FYI, I've done some research and found it out. Somebody did solve it, I don't know how they did it but they definitely removed the similar code that I've given here. You can found their code here: https://github.com/ImageOptim/ImageOptim/commit/dbc97f15b1b4d7468b1b74f4d43f87b68190e779

Comment: Please create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as the above code is insufficient to reproduce the problem you report.

Comment: And, did you try setting that breakpoint as the error suggested?

Comment: @Rob There is no such breakpoint. On MCVE, I'm very busy right now. I'll create it if I don't get any response in 2 days.

Comment: It seems this is a bug Apple introduced in Mojave. I would file a Radar with Apple.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits, you might be right. When I filtered `system.log` using this exact phrase, I found most of the apps have this message including Apple's Xcode, Finder, Spotlight, and even Terminal.

Comment: @JamesRisner: No, I didn't. Maybe CinderBiscuits did. I have taken a look at the system logs just now in Big Sur, and yes, I haven't seen these errors. But I do not know if the issue was fixed because I haven't developed apps using GCD for a while.